# Can I prevent Outlook from stripping webkit-text-size-adjust in HTML signatures?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I've got an HTML email signature that's working really well in all email clients, unless it's being sent from Outlook.

The main problem is that it's stripping out the webkit-text-size-adjust css so that emails received by iOS devices have huge malformed text.

How can I prevent Outlook from stripping this from the inline styles? Or is there a way to create styles that get ignored by not stripped by Outlook?